# Is it possible to write (display) exponential equations in scilab?

Tags: equation, display, exponential, scilab

I've been trying to display in my console an exponential equation like the following one:

```
y(t) = a*e^t + b*e^t + c*e^t
```

I would write it as a string, however the coefficients a,b and c, are numbers in a vector `V = [a b c]`. So I was trying to concatenate the numbers with strings "e^t", but I failed to do it. I know scilab displays polynomial equations, but I don't know it is possible to display exponential one. Anyone can help?

Comment: It might be helpful for users to know what have you tried. Care to describe your own attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of thing is done with [`mprintf`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/mprintf.html) command, which places given numerical arguments into a string with formatting instructions.

```
V = [3 5 -7]
mprintf("y(t) = %f*e^t + %f*e^t + %f*e^t", V)
```

The output is

```
y(t) = 3.000000*e^t + 5.000000*e^t + -7.000000*e^t
```

which isn't ideal, and can be improved in some ways by tweaking the formatters, but is readable regardless.

Notice we don't have to list every entry V(1), V(2), ... individually; the vector V gets "unpacked" automatically.

---

If you wanted to have 2D output like what we get for polynomials,

[image: polynomials in 2D]

then no, this kind of thing is what Scilab does for polynomials and rational functions only, not for general expressions.

There is also [prettyprint](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/prettyprint.html) but its output is LaTeX syntax, like `$1+s+s^{2}-s^{123}$`. It works for a few things: polynomials, rational functions, matrices...  but again, Scilab is not meant for symbolic manipulations, and does not really support symbolic expressions.